# Using constructors with arrays in D

Tags: arrays, constructor, d, dynamic-arrays

How do you call constructors when allocating an array with new?

For example, in the following code how would I call the constructor for each instantiation of A,  initialising b to 5 for all 10 elements?

```
void main() {
    A[] a = new A[10];
}

class A {
    int b;
    this(int init) {
        b = init;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it's not possible, but I can hope...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a simple loop should do (and it's the most readable)

```
foreach(ref el;a){
    el=new A(5);
}
```

or you can use the array initializer:

```
A[] a=[new A(5),new A(5),new A(5),new A(5),new A(5),
       new A(5),new A(5),new A(5),new A(5),new A(5)];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with a value type, you can use std.array.replicate.

```
auto a = replicate([5], 50);
```

would create an `int[]` of length 50 where each element is 5. You *can* do the same with a reference type, but all of the elements are going to refer to the same object.

```
auto a = replicate([new A(5)], 50);
```

will only call `A`'s constructor once, and you'll end up with an `A[]` where all of the elements refer to the same object. If you want them to refer to separate objects, you're either going to have to set each element individually

```
auto a = new A[](50);
foreach(ref e; a)
    e = new A(5);
```

or initialize the whole array with a literal

```
auto a = [new A(5), new A(5), new A(5)];
```

But that clearly will only work for relatively small arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in one line, you could write a macro to do it for you. I've borrowed code for the actual initialisation from the other answers.

```
template allocate(T) {
    T[] allocate(int size, int arg) {
        T[] result = new T[size];
        foreach(ref el; result)
            el=new T(arg);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can allocate an entire array of 10 elements at once with:

```
A[] a = allocate!(A)(10, 5);
```

Of course this has fixed constructor arguments, but you could probably do something with variadic arguments to the template and some mixins to generate the correct constructor call.